# Android Streaming and Recording at Once

Tags: streaming, full-hd, android

PROBLEM: Video should be streamed (Youtube) with low resolution for live view, but recorded in HD resolution for later review.

RESEARCH: I can stream and record separately. But using Android camera by two apps simultaneously is prohibited. Android 7 is used.

QUESTION: How to stream with low resolution and finally get video with high resolution?

Comment: The simple answer is that you need one piece of software that can handle both recording and streaming.  Product recommendations for a specific piece of software that can do this are likely to change frequently and probably aren't a great fit for the site.  You might have better luck on Software Recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy and suitable solution: 
launch Youtube **streaming app and Android screen capture** app at once. Only first app has monopolian access to camera in this case.

As of 2018, highest rated are [AZ Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free) and [DU Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duapps.recorder).

Thus I can stream outside low quality live and save to tablet with HD.

Answer (score 0):

Some background: when you want to use Camera in Android (as an application), you must setup it by specifying some constants. You must specify resolution, framerate, encoder options. This data usually used by internal CPU (DSP) for producing encoded stream in your hardware, you can't programm it. So, you must setup some options and get encoded stream for this options.

So, sorry, you can't use multiple applications at same time. At least, with different options (framerate).

But you can do workaround: you can decode HD stream, scaledown, encode again and stream to any service you want. This is very heavy task for CPU (in which apps works), so even if your phone can do it, it will very fast drain battery. Better way if to stream HD to some PC or server, recode it and re-stream to any other service.